# Python Code for Bulk Insert into SQL Server 2014 DateTime format

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime

This is a script that i run in python. I am getting a Bulk Load Conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) error.. for the datetime field.

```
Qry = "bulk insert tbl from 'c:\users\...\tbl.csv' with (fieldterminator = ',', firstrow = 2)"
cursor.execute(Qry)
```

my data is

Time Stamp,c1,c2,c3,c4

"7/16/2015 0:05",0,0,0,3.84
...

How do i set my 
SET DATEFORMAT ####; code in python before executing the bulk insert? Also, an additional question. How do i get SQL Server to ignore the double quotes around the datatime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with the following statement (you can put it on a single line):

```
set dateformat mdy;
bulk insert tbl from 'c:\users\...\tbl.csv' with (fieldterminator = ',', firstrow = 2);
```

mind the closing semicolon: it tells sql where the first command ends and the next one begins.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes the TimeStamp data in the entire file comes in with double quotes enclosing the date time. Is there a simple way have SQL Server ignore the double quote enclosure?

Comment: i don't know. i suppose it is not that easy because i don't think that the bulk command has somewhat advanced parsing capabilities...